# Autocorrelation robust standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation, autocorrelation

I have a time series following an AR(p) structure for which I want to calculate the variance using the usual formula:

$$sd = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x-\bar{x})^2$$

However, I know that the usual variance calculation is biased. Is there a way to calculate an autocorrelation robust variance.

I have considered the practice based on this [unbiased estimation of standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation), but in my case I do not known the autocorrelation function; I can only estimate it.

So my question is, is there a way to calculate an autocorrelation-robust variance from sample data Witherspoon autocorrelation?

Comment: is the $\sigma^2$ estimate that comes out of an AR(p) estimation algorithm biased ? I'm not saying that you're wrong but could you send the book or paper that says this. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I see, I think I need to reformulate my question. I am not estimating an AR(p). I just have a time series, that has autocorrelation. On this time series, I calculate a standard deviation using the standard formula for the standard deviation (no AR-estimation).

Comment: You’ve given the equation for an unbiased estimator of variance. Do you mean variance or standard deviation? (Amazingly, the square root of an unbiased estimator of variance is biased for standard deviation. I think my first answer on here was about that.)

Comment: Thank you. I am that the problem, but to keeper it simple, I'll Edit my question yo be about the variance.

Comment: @Dave, the point is that the unbiased estimator becomes biased under autocorrelation. I think the focus here is on the effect of autocorrelation and what to do about it.

Comment: @RVA92: I'm not familiar with what you're doing so I can't help.  I'll just sit quietly and follow it as best as I can. ( and hopefully learn something ).  I don't know if this is relevant but just a heads up that,  if you want to calculate the variance of a sum of RV's that are correlated, then, you need to add up all the variances of the RV's in the sum and all the covariances of the RV's in the sum.  The sample variance would similarly use the estimates of those things.